# Woocommerce cart text change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to change the text on the cart page
from

> YOU HAVE 1 ITEM IN YOUR CART

to

> YOU HAVE 1 VOUCHER IN YOUR CART

The file that outputs this text is `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php`
and it uses a hook called `woocommerce_before_cart_table` I cannot find any information on this function.

Other people suggested changing the woocommerce language files, but this cart text is not in the language files either.

Please help

Comment: You probably mean this action : `woocommerce_before_cart`